# Почему так работает валидация формы?

Tags: jquery, validate

```
$('form').validate({
   ignore: [],
   invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
     var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();

     if (errors) {//если ошибки есть
         var errorEl = $(this).find('select.error');//select которым нужно работать
         errorEl.siblings().find('p').addClass('error');//добавляю класс для соседнего p

         errorEl.change(function() {//изменение состояния select
           errorEl.siblings().find('p').removeClass('error');
         });

       return false;

     } else {
       errorEl.siblings().find('p').removeClass('error');
       return true;
     }
     return;
   }
});

<div class="select-wrapper">
  <div class="styled-dropdown">
    <p class="">Choose a Group...</p> //довавление класса error
    <ul class="styled-dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
      <li id="">Choose a Group...</li>
      <li id="34">Daily Work</li>
      <li id="35">Assignments</li>
      <li id="36">Quizzes</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <select class="activity-group-dropdown conditional-dropdown " required="required" name="activity[activity_group_id]" id="activity_activity_group_id" style="display: none;" aria-required="true">
   <option value="">Choose a Group...</option>
   <option value="34">Daily Work</option>
   <option value="35">Assignments</option>
   <option value="36">Quizzes</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Использую **jquery.validate**. Если элемент не прошел валидацию - он получает класс **error** и нужно для его соседнего элемента добавлять класс **error**.
В моем случае **select** получает класс **error** при клике по кнопке (валидация работает), но его соседний элемент **.styled-dropdown p** - не получает класс **error** и нужно делать второй клик по кнопке - и вот тогда класс **error** уже добавляется. Выходит нужно два клика делать что есть неправильно. Как это исправить? И второе что сейчас я обращаюсь к конкретному select с id а форм может быть несколько - нужно обращение делать универсальным ( в каждой форме могут быть такие select)

Попробовал вот такое решение:

```
$(this).validate({
            ignore: [],
            messages: {
                required: true
            },
            invalidHandler: function() {
                var validEl = $('#activity_activity_group_id');
                validEl.siblings().find('p').addClass('error');

                validEl.change(function() {
                    validEl.siblings().find('p').removeClass('error');
                });
            }
        });
```

это работает, но как его сделать универсальным для разных форм (если убираю id оставляя только select) то скрипт работает не корректно. Нужно решение универсальное для всех псевдоселектов их может быть в этой форме несколько.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $('form').validate({
            ignore: 'input[type=hidden], textarea[type=hidden]',
            rules: {
                required: true
            },
            messages: {
                required: true
            },
            invalidHandler: function() {
                var errorList = '';

                setTimeout(function(){
                    var errorList = $('select.error');
                    errorList.siblings().find('p').addClass('error');
                    $('label.error').css('display', 'block');

                    errorList.change(function() {
                      errorList.siblings().find('p').removeClass('error');
                      $('label.error').css('display', 'none');
                    });
                },1);
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

немного рефакторинга и вуаля все ок!